# JavaPlot: Is there anyway to replot the data in the same plot instead of creating a new graphic?

Tags: java, gnuplot, javaplot

I was trying to monitor the change of some parameters using JavaPlot.

Is there a way to simply update the plot of data in the original plot?

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot do this with JavaPlot.

JavaPlot doesn't have a single gnuplot instance running in the background which it pipes commands to. For every plot it creates a new temporary file which is then called with gnuplot. That means, that after using `p.plot()` you don't have any access to the gnuplot window containing the plot.

Consider the following short example:

```
import com.panayotis.gnuplot.JavaPlot;
import com.panayotis.gnuplot.utils.Debug;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JavaPlot p = new JavaPlot();
    p.getDebugger().setLevel(Debug.INFO);
        p.addPlot("sin(x)");
        p.plot();
    p.plot();
    }
}
```

That opens two windows and prints the messages:

```
** Start of plot commands **
plot sin(x) title 'sin(x)'
quit
** End of plot commands **
exec(/usr/bin/gnuplot /tmp/gnuplot_5778913101279507298.dat -persist )
** Start of plot commands **
plot sin(x) title 'sin(x)'
quit
** End of plot commands **
exec(/usr/bin/gnuplot /tmp/gnuplot_4590356376057662873.dat -persist )
```

You see that two different temporary files are created.

Comment: Thank you very much..... I guess this means I need to write the graphic interface by myself... =( sigh

Comment: Depending on your other requirements it might be enough to extend the `GNUPlotExec` class to add an finite or infinite loop at the end of the script file: `iter = 0; while (iter < 100) { refresh; iter = iter+1; pause 5; }`.